# Is this subalgebra semisimple?

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Denote by $\mathfrak{g}$ a complex semisimple Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. 
Let $\Phi$
be the root system of $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h})$ and denote by $\mathfrak{g}_\alpha$ the root subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponding
to a root $\alpha$.
We fix a choice of positive roots $\Phi^+$, and let $\Delta$ be the corresponding subset of simple roots in $\Phi^+$. Note that each subset $I\subseteq\Delta$ generates a root system $\Phi_I\subseteq\Phi$, with positive roots $\Phi_I^+:=\Phi_I\cap \Phi^+$.

Let 
$
\mathfrak{l}_I:=\mathfrak{h}\oplus\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi_I}\mathfrak{g}_\alpha
$.

**My questions:**

1. Is $\mathfrak{l}_I$ complex semsimple? If so, why?
2. Is $\mathfrak{l}_I$ a Levi subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Rarely semi-simple, because $\mathfrak h$ is too big, but invariably reductive.

Comment: However, when $I=\Delta$, we get $\mathfrak{l}_I=\mathfrak{g}$ is complex semisimple while the $\mathfrak{h}$ is still big. How to explain this?

Comment: Well, in the semi-simple case all of $\mathfrak h$ is hit by brackets from the root spaces, while this is not so for proper $I$.

Comment: One thing that helps would be to figure out the centre of $\mathfrak{l}_I$.